# SQL: Selecting two different things and doing calculations on the results in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to pull two things from my database: entries where one attribute is TRUE and the entries where the attribute is FALSE. I then want to divide the first result by the second result to get a percentage of entries where the attribute is TRUE.

```
SELECT product, COUNT(entries) FROM myTable 
WHERE has_bug = 1
AND date > "2014-07-01"
GROUP BY product

SELECT product, COUNT(entries) FROM myTable 
WHERE has_bug = 0
AND date > "2014-07-01"
GROUP BY product
```

I get the results fine, and I can do the division separately, but is it possible to divide the results of these two SELECT statements in this one query?

EDIT:
This did the trick:

```
SELECT product, SUM(has_bug = 1) / SUM(has_bug = 0)
FROM myTable 
WHERE date > "2014-07-01"
GROUP BY product
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (ab)use MySQL's automatic type-conversion logic:

```
SELECT product, (SUM(entries = 0) / SUM(entries = 1)) AS ratio
FROM myTable 
WHERE date > '2014-07-01'
GROUP BY product
```

The boolean true/false of the `entries = X` comparisons will get converted to integer `0` or `1` by MySQL, and summed up, essentially reproducing your `COUNT()`, but in a single query.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! 
SELECT product, SUM(has_bug = 1) / SUM(has_bug = 0) ...

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation.  Actually, the following will do what you want, assuming `has_bug` only takes on the values of `0` and `1`:

```
select product, avg(has_bug) 
from mytable
where date > '2014-07-01'
group by product;
```

A more explicit match to your query is:

```
select product, sum(has_bug = 1) / count(*)
from mytable
where date > '2014-07-01'
group by product;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
Product ,
(case when has_bug=1 then count(entries) else 0 end) as Bug , 
(case when has_bug=0 then count(entries) else 0 end) as NoBug ,
((case when has_bug=1 then count(entries) else 0 end) /
(case when has_bug=0 then count(entries) else 0 end)) as Percentage
from Mytable 
WHERE 
date > "2014-07-01"
GROUP BY product
```

Answer (score 0):

you code depends on what your output format needs to look like.  I would try this

```
SELECT Product, has_bug, cnt, (cnt/SUM(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY product)) cntovrttl
FROM(
SELECT product, has_bug, COUNT(entries) as cnt
FROM myTable 
WHERE date > "2014-07-01"
GROUP BY product, has_bug) tbl1
```

Brad